# Searching an Immutable Map by key value

Tags: facebook, immutability, immutable.js

Using Facebook [Immutable](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js). How can i search an immutable map for a key value. In the below structure.

```
    {
        issue: 328,
        version: 1,
        filename: '328-1',
        title: 'The Lorem ipsum dolor cover',
        date: {
            year: 2015,
            month: 8,
            day: 22
        }
    },
    {
        issue: 329,
        version: 2,
        filename: '328-2',
        title: 'The Lorem ipsum dolor cover',
        date: {
            year: 2015,
            month: 8,
            day: 22
        }
    },
```

I need to search for all 'issue' with the same value and then search 'version' value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ok worked it out using [findEntry](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/findEntry) and passing a function to it

```
_t.findEntry(function(obj){return obj.get('issue') ===328 && obj.get('version') === 1;})
```